# Entity Framework Core error occures when trying to include other entity

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, foreign-keys

I am working with some entities which are connected by foreign keys using the Entity Framework code-first approach. When I try to include one from another I get an error that says:
***The expression 'user.Organization' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access***

These are my classes:

```
    public class User : Person
    {
        public StaffRole? Role { get; set; } = null;

        [ForeignKey(nameof(Organization))]
        public Guid? OrganizationId { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public virtual Organization Organization { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class Organization : Auditable
    {
        public Organization()
        {
            Staffs = new List<User>();
        }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<User> Staffs { get; set; }
    }
```

I have removed some properties in order to be clear.
This is how I am trying to include

```
 var owner = userRepository.GetAll(user => user.Id == currentUser.Id &&
         user.Role == StaffRole.Owner).Include(user => user.Organization).FirstOrDefault();
```

I have looked around the Web to find the answer but I think I need a little bit of individual help.

Comment: Actually problem that `Organization` marked as `NotMapped` Why?